# Save data from JTextField in columns in .csv File

Tags: java, swing, csv, file-io, save

I have the coded the following program to get user input in four JTextFields and than saves it in a .csv file. But I am getting it in different rows. I want the output in the .csv file to be from column to column

My code is as follows:

```
public class panel extends FirstClick {

               final JTextField items;
               final JTextField number;
               final JTextField cost;
               final JTextField amount;

              public panel() {    
                  JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();    
                    myFrame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

                    myFrame.setTitle("GUI Demo - ISTE-121");
                    myFrame.pack();
                    myFrame.setLocation(600,300);
                    myFrame.setSize(400,200);
                    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    myFrame.setVisible(true);

              JPanel order = new JPanel();
              order.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5,2,2));

              myFrame.add(order, BorderLayout.CENTER);

              order.add(new JLabel("Item no:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
              order.add(items = new JTextField(3));

              order.add(new JLabel("Number of:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
              order.add(number = new JTextField(3));

              order.add(new JLabel("Cost", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
              order.add(cost = new JTextField(3));

              order.add(new JLabel("Amount owed:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
              order.add(amount = new JTextField(10));
              amount.setEditable(false);                  

              JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
              buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,2,2));

          myFrame.add(buttons ,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

              JButton calculate;
              buttons.add(calculate=new JButton("Calculate"));

              calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
              {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    double cost1 = new Double(cost.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
                    double number1 = new Double(number.getText().trim()).doubleValue();

                    double result =  cost1*number1;
                    amount.setText(String.valueOf(result));                     
                }                     
              });

              JButton save;
              buttons.add(save = new JButton("Save"));

              save.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

                    // The name of the file to open.
                    String fileName = "temp1.csv";    
                    try {
                        // Assume default encoding.
                        FileWriter fileWriter =
                            new FileWriter(fileName, true);

                        // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                            new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

                        // Note that write() does not automatically
                        // append a newline character.
                        bufferedWriter.write(items.getText());
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();
                        bufferedWriter.write(number.getText());
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();
                        bufferedWriter.write(cost.getText());
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();
                        bufferedWriter.write(amount.getText());
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();
                        // Always close files.
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(
                            "Error writing to file '"
                            + fileName + "'");
                        // Or we could just do this:
                        // ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }}  
                );

              JButton clear;
              buttons.add(clear=new JButton("Clear"));

              clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     items.setText(null);
                     number.setText(null);
                     cost.setText(null);
                     amount.setText(null);
                }});

              JButton exit;
              buttons.add(exit= new JButton("Exit"));

               exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
               {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              System.exit(0);

            }
               });

        }
}



public class FirstClick {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        panel second = new panel();


    }  // end main
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you write  a newLine between your fields

remove the newLine() call and replace with a write of ';'

```
bufferedWriter.write(items.getText());
bufferedWriter.write(';');
bufferedWriter.write(number.getText());
bufferedWriter.write(';');
```

Comment: I am getting the following input on the excel sheet:

item 600;3;3;9.0;
I want it in separate field of the column

Comment: The output is coming in one single cell, like:
item 600;3;3;9.0;

I want it from column to column

Comment: then you Excel is actin up. read http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/2293-i-have-trouble-opening-csv-files-with-microsoft-excel-is-there-a-quick-way-to-fix-this and google for other similar text or use third party program like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Replicate this pattern in CSV:

> "Label","Value"

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/CSV/data.csv");
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bufferedWriter.write("\"ItemCode\","+"\""+items.getText()+"\"");
bufferedWriter.write("\"ItemNumber\","+"\""+number.getText()+"\"");
bufferedWriter.write("\"ItemCost\","+"\""+cost.getText()+"\"");
bufferedWriter.write("\"AmountOwned\","+"\""+amount.getText()+"\"");

bufferedWriter.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think its almost done. Its just that I am getting something like this in the excel file:
       A                        B                          C                            D                    E
Item number        444''Number of      5''Cost of              45''Amount      225

I am getting them in columns but the JTextField value for items is coming in numbers, and for numbers its coming in cost of

Comment: What you meant by "JTextField value for items is coming in numbers" JTextField.getText() == String, Better check your UI